# Filtering in Pandas dataframe slow for "large" number of groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 200k rows, which I'm trying to filter as follows:

```
>>> df.groupby(key).filter(lambda group: len(group) > 100)
```

where key is a list of columns. This runs in about 3 seconds when the key specified divides the dataframe into 800 or so groups. However, if I add another column to the key, increasing the number of groups to around 2500, the execution sucks up all my memory and basically crashes my system unless I terminate the script.

I can do the same by iterating over the groups, but it's clumsy compared to the above one-liner, and makes me wonder why the filter function is so limited.

Could someone please explain to me if this is to be expected, and if so why?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of pandas do you have?

Comment: show df.info() and your key

Comment: I use version 0.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat dependent on the number of groups, but something else must be going on for you. This is pretty fast.

```
In [10]: N = 1000000

In [11]: ngroups = 1000

In [12]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randint(0,ngroups,size=N),B=np.random.randn(N)))

In [13]: %timeit df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 431 ms per loop

In [14]: df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1000).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 508918 entries, 0 to 999997
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    508918 non-null int64
B    508918 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
In [15]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randint(0,10,size=N),B=np.random.randn(N)))

In [16]: %timeit df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 182 ms per loop

In [17]: df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1000).info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    1000000 non-null int64
B    1000000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer and I'm sorry for my slow response! Indeed, your code runs quickly on my PC as well, even when I increase the number of groups to 2500. Something else must be happening!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. One of the columns contains dates that I have represented as Timestamp objects. When I convert the Timestamp objects to strings, the grouping works quickly without problems!

Comment: not sure what you are talking about; this was a bug fixed in 0.14.0

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above I'm using 13.1.