# count rows by certain combination of row values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, row

I have a dataframe (df) like this:

```
  v1    v2  v3
   0    -30 -15
   0    -30 -7.5
   0    -30 -11.25
   0    -30 -13.125
   0    -30 -14.0625
   0    -30 -13.59375
   0    -10 -5
   0    -10 -7.5
   0    -10 -6.25
   0    -10 -5.625
   0    -10 -5.9375
   0    -10 -6.09375
   0    -5  -2.5
   0    -5  -1.25
   0    -5  -1.875
```

The rows are in the same chunk if with certain/same `v1` and `v2`. In this case, rows with`([0,-30], [0,-10], [0,-5])`. I want to split the rows in chunks and count the number of rows in this chunk. If the length of the rows is not 6, then remove the whole chunk, otherwise, keep this chunk.

My rough codes:

```
v1_ls = df.v1.unique()
v2_ls = df.v2.unique()
for i, j in v1_ls, v2_ls: 
   chunk[i] = df[(df['v1'] == v1_ls[i]) & df['v2'] == v2_ls[j]]

   if len(chunk[i])!= 6:
      df = df[df != chunk[i]]
   else:
      pass
```

expected output:

```
  v1    v2  v3
   0    -30 -15
   0    -30 -7.5
   0    -30 -11.25
   0    -30 -13.125
   0    -30 -14.0625
   0    -30 -13.59375
   0    -10 -5
   0    -10 -7.5
   0    -10 -6.25
   0    -10 -5.625
   0    -10 -5.9375
   0    -10 -6.09375
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in `v1` and `v2` are no `NaN`s, so use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])['v2'].transform('size') == 6]
print (df)
    v1  v2        v3
0    0 -30 -15.00000
1    0 -30  -7.50000
2    0 -30 -11.25000
3    0 -30 -13.12500
4    0 -30 -14.06250
5    0 -30 -13.59375
6    0 -10  -5.00000
7    0 -10  -7.50000
8    0 -10  -6.25000
9    0 -10  -5.62500
10   0 -10  -5.93750
11   0 -10  -6.09375
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])['v2'].transform('size') == 6)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
Name: v2, dtype: bool
```

Unfortunately `filter` is really slow, so if need better performance use `transform`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcdefghijkl') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'v2':np.random.randint(10000,size=N),
                   'value':np.random.randint(1000,size=N),
                   'value2':np.random.randint(5000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['v1','v2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df.head(10))

In [290]: %timeit df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 6)
1 loop, best of 3: 12.1 s per loop

In [291]: %timeit df[df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])['v2'].transform('size') == 6]
1 loop, best of 3: 176 ms per loop

In [292]: %timeit df[df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).v2.transform('count').eq(6)]
10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop
```

---

```
N = 1000000

ngroups = 1000

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = np.random.randint(0,ngroups,size=N),B=np.random.randn(N)))

In [299]: %timeit df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1000)
1 loop, best of 3: 330 ms per loop

In [300]: %timeit df[df.groupby(['A'])['A'].transform('size') > 1000]
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**

The results do not address performance given the number of groups, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly shocking / a regression? The original implementation by Dan Allen was introduced as a speed up. I'm guessing some fiddling has been done to the implemenation since then :/

Comment: I have no idea, maybe `transform` implementation was improved a lot ;) But I am not pandas dev, so hard answer for me ;)

Comment: I'm guessing related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291492/1240268 (your example is a worst case for number of groups edit: it's no _wost_ case actually... just a lot of 'em, and we're stuck in python with the lambda).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, so use your suggestion. Now only 3 times slowier

Comment: It is getting harder and harder for me to keep my silence when you keep posting near identical answers to mine... the other day you posted the same thing with a list comprehension, this time it was a groupby and transform with the only difference being size/count, which would make 0 difference here. I'm requesting you (very nicely) to refrain from doing this again.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Yes, it is nearly same. So sorry. But I think my answer is more valueable because timings (and create timings for groupby is really hard :( ). And list comprehension was expplained from me, or not?

Comment: Next time, I'll write the same answer as yours and add timings, and then argue that my answer is more valuable than yours. Adding timings doesn't justify posting the same thing when you could've just... added a comment or whatever.

Comment: And some can argue that a loop is better than a list comprehension, so it's subjective.

Comment: OK, if it will be different like me `count` vs `size` + `timings` then it is perfectly OK and I have no problem. I really like timings, because it force for read more optimalize solutions.

Comment: Do you remember the times you've forced me to delete my answers in the past because of similarities to yours? I'm sure _those_ differences were much larger than this, but I didn't say anything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - yes, I remember. Only difference was name of columns, else was same...

Comment: It wasn't just that, but I don't want to argue about it, since it seems pointless to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` + `count/size`:

```
df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).v3.transform('count')

0     6.0
1     6.0
2     6.0
3     6.0
4     6.0
5     6.0
6     6.0
7     6.0
8     6.0
9     6.0
10    6.0
11    6.0
12    3.0
13    3.0
14    3.0
Name: v3, dtype: float64
```

Use the mask to filter `df`:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).v3.transform('count').eq(6)]    # == 6
df

    v1  v2        v3
0    0 -30 -15.00000
1    0 -30  -7.50000
2    0 -30 -11.25000
3    0 -30 -13.12500
4    0 -30 -14.06250
5    0 -30 -13.59375
6    0 -10  -5.00000
7    0 -10  -7.50000
8    0 -10  -6.25000
9    0 -10  -5.62500
10   0 -10  -5.93750
11   0 -10  -6.09375
```

`count` does not count `NaN`s, while `size` does. Use whatever is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) groupby method:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 6)
Out[11]:
    v1  v2        v3
0    0 -30 -15.00000
1    0 -30  -7.50000
2    0 -30 -11.25000
3    0 -30 -13.12500
4    0 -30 -14.06250
5    0 -30 -13.59375
6    0 -10  -5.00000
7    0 -10  -7.50000
8    0 -10  -6.25000
9    0 -10  -5.62500
10   0 -10  -5.93750
11   0 -10  -6.09375
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 6)` ?

Comment: @jezrael that's the one :) (though I think from rereading the question it's actually == )

Comment: `filter`'s one method I've never seemed to use... maybe I should start.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it used to be transform was the only way, filter was written to be more efficient (cythonized basically) IIRC.

Comment: @AndyHayden - Hmmm, by my experience `filter` is really slow, see my timings in my answer.